# PHP merge array with similar keys, and sum some keys

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, array-merge

I really struggled with this more than a day before bothering this awesome comunity, but I havent had any luck.

I have an array that looks like this

```
$Data = [
  [
   'code' => 'P-01',
   'firstname' => 'Sam',
   'lastname' => 'Bouchard',
   'quantity' => 3
  ],
 [
   'code' => 'P-09',
   'firstname' => 'Roy',
   'lastname' => 'Gauthier',
   'quantity' => 14
  ],
 [
   'code' => 'P-24',
   'firstname' => 'Marin',
   'lastname' => 'Fortin',
   'quantity' => 24
  ],
 [
   'code' => 'P-03',
   'firstname' => 'Sam',
   'lastname' => 'Bouchard',
   'quantity' => 7
  ],
 [
   'code' => 'P-01',
   'firstname' => 'Sam',
   'lastname' => 'Bouchard',
   'quantity' => 9
  ],
];
```

SO i want to merge array so I have array like this

```
$Data = [
  [
   'firstname' => 'Sam',
   'lastname' => 'Bouchard',
   'combined' => [
     'code' => 'P-01',
     'quantity' => 12 
   ],
   [
     'code'=> 'P-03',
     'quantity' => 7
   ]
  ],
  [
   'firstname' => 'Roy',
   'lastname' => 'Gauthier',
   'combined' => [
     'code' => 'P-09',
     'quantity' => 14 
   ]
  ],
  [
   'firstname' => 'Marin',
   'lastname' => 'Fortin',
   'combined' => [
     'code' => 'P-24',
     'quantity' => 24
   ]
  ],
];
```

as you can see, if 'code' is same, I need to sum quantity.
Thanks in advance

Comment: show us what you've tried, your best attempt (code) and where you are stuck. What error(s) do you get? Suggest you read [ask].

Comment: This is easily done with a couple of loops, see below. However, @jibsteroos is right SO generally requires that you provide at least an attempt to fix your problem - even if you don't get anywhere near close! - the ethos is that of we're here to **help fix** not **write for you**.

Comment: I managed to solve here https://pastebin.com/D0vw3Na5

Answer (score 0):

In the following example, you get new merged array with unique code keys. Also, it adds the previous quantity to the following one.

```php
$Merged = [];
foreach ($Data as $value) {
  if (isset($Merged[$value['code']])) {
    $Merged[$value['code']]['quantity'] += $value['quantity'];
  } else {
    $Merged[$value['code']] = $value;
  }
}
```

Output

```php
Array
(
    [P-01] => Array
        (
            [code] => P-01
            [firstname] => Sam
            [lastname] => Bouchard
            [quantity] => 12
        )

    [P-09] => Array
        (
            [code] => P-09
            [firstname] => Roy
            [lastname] => Gauthier
            [quantity] => 14
        )

    [P-24] => Array
        (
            [code] => P-24
            [firstname] => Marin
            [lastname] => Fortin
            [quantity] => 24
        )

    [P-03] => Array
        (
            [code] => P-03
            [firstname] => Sam
            [lastname] => Bouchard
            [quantity] => 7
        )

)
```

Comment: This isn't in the right format? The question required names to be combined as well as quantities I.e `P-01 == P-03`

Comment: @Steven I think his purpose to sum the quantity

Comment: Yes, I agree that looks to be the main goal. But in the OPs _output_ it looks as though he has also grouped by name?

Comment: @Steven that's mentioned in the way he wants. The first name and last name in the same array with the code.

Answer (score 0):

### Input data

Note that your shown array has a few errors in formatting (presumably typos). We'll use:

```
$data = [
  [
   'code' => 'P-01',
   'firstname' => 'Sam',
   'lastname' => 'Bouchard',
   'quantity' => 3
  ],
 [
   'code' => 'P-09',
   'firstname' => 'Roy',
   'lastname' => 'Gauthier',
   'quantity' => 14
  ],
 [
   'code' => 'P-24',
   'firstname' => 'Marin',
   'lastname' => 'Fortin',
   'quantity' => 24
  ],
 [
   'code' => 'P-03',
   'firstname' => 'Sam',
   'lastname' => 'Bouchard',
   'quantity' => 7
  ],
 [
   'code' => 'P-01',
   'firstname' => 'Sam',
   'lastname' => 'Bouchard',
   'quantity' => 9
  ]
];
```

### Transform the array

Firstly we want to transform the array into a data structure we can easily work with and at the same time we can combine and update the quantities.

In this case we'll reorganise indexing on three levels `firstname -> lastname -> code`

```
// Define the array for output of transformation
$firstnameIndexArray = [];

// Loop through all current data points
foreach($data as $point){

    // Set a pointer by reference to decrease the length of the next line(!) hopefully 
    // making it more readable
    $pointer   = &$firstnameIndexArray[$point['firstname']][$point['lastname']][$point['code']];

    // Update the quantity
    // $pointer ?? 0... sets to 0 if $pointer doesn't contain a value/exist
    $pointer   = ($pointer ?? 0) + $point["quantity"];
}
```

Now that we've done that we have an array which looks like:

```
Array
(
    [Sam] => Array
        (
            [Bouchard] => Array
                (
                    [P-01] => 12
                    [P-03] => 7
                )

        )

    [Roy] => Array
        (
            [Gauthier] => Array
                (
                    [P-09] => 14
                )

        )

    [Marin] => Array
        (
            [Fortin] => Array
                (
                    [P-24] => 24
                )

        )

)
```

### Remake array in correct format

Now all that's left to do is loop through the transformed array and output in a format of our choosing...

```
// Define the output array
$finalArray = [];

// Loop through first level of array
foreach($firstnameIndexArray as $firstname => $lastnameIndexarray){

    // Loop through second level of array
    foreach($lastnameIndexarray as $lastname => $codeIndexArray){

        // Define the combined array of code/value pairs
        $combinedArray = [];

        // Loop though each code/value pair
        foreach($codeIndexArray as $code => $quantity){

            // Make the combined array in the correct format
            $combinedArray[] = [
                'code'     => $code,
                'quantity' => $quantity
            ];
        }

        // Add the person to the final array
        $finalArray[] = [
            'firstname' => $firstname,
            'lastname' => $lastname,
            'combined' => $combinedArray
        ];
    }
}
```

Which gives output like:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [firstname] => Sam
            [lastname] => Bouchard
            [combined] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [code] => P-01
                            [quantity] => 12
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [code] => P-03
                            [quantity] => 7
                        )

                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [firstname] => Roy
            [lastname] => Gauthier
            [combined] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [code] => P-09
                            [quantity] => 14
                        )

                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [firstname] => Marin
            [lastname] => Fortin
            [combined] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [code] => P-24
                            [quantity] => 24
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

### Code without comments

```
$firstnameIndexArray = [];
foreach($data as $point){
    $pointer   = &$firstnameIndexArray[$point['firstname']][$point['lastname']][$point['code']];
    $pointer   = ($pointer ?? 0) + $point["quantity"];
}

$finalArray = [];
foreach($firstnameIndexArray as $firstname => $lastnameIndexarray){
    foreach($lastnameIndexarray as $lastname => $codeIndexArray){
        $combinedArray = [];
        foreach($codeIndexArray as $code => $quantity){
            $combinedArray[] = [
                'code'     => $code,
                'quantity' => $quantity
            ];
        }
        $finalArray[] = [
            'firstname' => $firstname,
            'lastname' => $lastname,
            'combined' => $combinedArray
        ];
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Possible approach is to use 'code' as an index for a new array:

Create a new result array

```
$combined = [];
```

Loop through $Data and put each item in $item
For each $item get the code as $key
Check if you already have a value in the combined array with that $key

```
if (isset($combined[$key]))) {...}
```

if not, add item to array using that $key

```
$newItem = $this->createNewStructureFromItem($item);
$combined[$key] = $newItem;
```

If you already have that key in the combined array, only update the quantity

```
$existingItem = $combined[$key];
$updatedItem = $this->increaseQuantity($existingItem, $item);
$combined[$key] = $updatedItem;
```